# The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: Mux-Stats-AVPlayer/XCFramework/MUXSDKStats.xcframework

Tags: flutter, frameworks, cocoapods, avplayer, gorilla

Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.3.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 52b3dc25f6 (2 weeks ago) • 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
Engine • revision 857bd6b74c
Tools • Dart 2.18.4 • DevTools 2.15.0

And I have this problem when I run my project with Pod Install.

Anyone know how can I solve it?